# Поведение Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добрый день возможно вы сможете помочь.

Ситуация такая пишу приложение с двумя фрагментами в один из них добавил ImageView в макет фрагмента

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

В классе фрагмента пытаюсь связать через getView();

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    View view = getView();
    if(view != null){
        ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Actor actor = Actor.actors[actorList];
        image.setImageResource(actor.getPathImage());
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(actor.getName());
    }
}
```

Выбрасывается исключение ClassCastException на строке связывания ImageView

Все стираю и вручную через design конструктор добавляю по новой элементы и связываю.

В итоге все работает.
Что это может быть? Gradle не трогал.

Comment: причем здесь android studio? что вы в коде пишите, то и происходит. заголовок должен содержать краткую суть проблемы, а не абстрактное нечто. на какой строке ошибка приведения к типу и полный текст ошибки в вопрос добавьте

Comment: Добавьте лучше весь класс фрагмента в пример, особенно `onCreate`

Comment: Что за странная конструкция view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);?

Comment: А почему в методе `onStart()`? Почему не в методе `onCreateView()`?

Comment: Все сложно (((((((((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
public void onCreate() {
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Actor actor = Actor.actors[actorList];
    image.setImageResource(actor.getPathImage());
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(actor.getName());
}
```

Comment: Все работает спасибо надо было жизненный цикл поправить